# How to add Google analytics to android app widget?

Tags: android-widget, google-analytics

I've been struggle to had Google analytics to my app widget, without any success, The code works fine when using from Activity but not from the app widget.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this code inside your AppWidgetProvider onEnabled() method

```
 Tracker t = ((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getTracker(
            MyApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

 // Set screen name.
 t.setScreenName(screenName);

 // Send a screen view.
 t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

Comment: onEnabled() only works for checking when a user installs the app widget for the first time.

What about attaching analytics to certain intents launched from the widget itself?